# Laravel 9 Register blade view not work properly

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

using Laravel 9 and installed `php artisan ui vue --auth` command and create Login and Register components as well. and run `npm install` and `npm run dev` command also. but when I try to load Register or Login blade files following error encounted
`Vite manifest not found at: F:\2023\laravel ecommerce\shop\public\build/manifest.json`

`F:\2023\laravel ecommerce\shop\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php : 17 require`

resources\views\layouts\app.blade

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!-- CSRF Token -->

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">


    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>


    <!-- Fonts -->

    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.bunny.net">

    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Scripts -->

    @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])  // this is line 17

</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">

            <div class="container">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">

                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}

                </a>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">

                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

                </button>


                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
```

how could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
 F:\2023\laravel ecommerce\shop\public\build/manifest.json
```

Contains a forward slash but you are on windows, you should check where this file is configured

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
 
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
});
```

Take a look at: [laravel with vite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#installing-vite-and-laravel-plugin)

You should indeed run npm rum build to generate manifest.json as pointed out before running npm run dev

Comment: error `can not find laravel vite plugin`

Comment: I updated my answer. Learning a i go. Did you update laravel to 9?